# How to cast an object to its own class?

Tags: swift, casting

How can I cast an object into its own class?

So instead of writing this:

```
    switch object {
    case is ClassA:
        return object as! ClassA

    case is ClassB:
        return object as! ClassB  
    }
```

I am looking for a short form like:

```
return object as! object.class // which does not work
```

Comment: What's the return type of your function?

Comment: The function returns a custom UITableViewCell. It's the function tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath...). Actually this smells like bad code design, so to clearify: The table view uses an array <AnyObject> and has to cast it to custom UITableViewCell classes.

Comment: If all objects are `UITableViewCell` subclasses, you could cast `AnyObject` to `UITableViewCell`, regardless of the actual type.

Comment: Take a look at generics maybe? If it fits your usage

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are absolutely right. The tableView doesn't care about the subclassing of it's cells because it only looks at the parent UITableViewCell class anyway. If you add this as answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @Manuel Sure - I'm glad that it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function returns a custom `UITableViewCell`.  [...] The table view uses an array `<AnyObject>` and has to cast it to custom `UITableViewCell` classes

Since all objects are custom `UITableViewCell` subclasses, you could cast `AnyObject` to `UITableViewCell`, regardless of the actual type. This should be sufficient, because `UITable` does not need to know about the type beyond the `UITableViewCell` base type.